# Why "ls" command highlights some folders?

Tags: bash, ls

Why `LS` highlights folder `PyFac` ? How disable this highlighting?

[IMG](https://leto1g.storage.yandex.net/rdisk/1869f33eed3dd3aec0cb90ce2dc7267a97c01c4d8dee86afec2175f2e9c49516/inf/FXXq2HB08u-QK9cthER-CvUy3vYWoIJVFZyeE_KnRT22gjuKQLjdKVQpbBNQSCtYo3oBITVIXXanCk0UB3GFMg==?uid=0&filename=Screen%20Shot%202015-06-17%20at%2023.30.16.png&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fpng&tknv=v2&rtoken=876553fcd08c3e4d9acc94b407c85688&force_default=no)

My `.profile`:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
export CLICOLOR=1
export TERM="xterm-256color"
PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
```

Comment: You might be interested in http://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-the-terminal

Comment: once: `\ls` or for current shell: `unalias ls`.

Comment: Try `ls --color=never`

Comment: Take a deep look at `man ls`.